# What is the Best Practise to use the managed service accounts and service accounts for staging environment?

Tags: 2013, installation, managed-account, staging

For preparing staging environment for sharepoint 2013 what is the best practise
to create managed service accounts and service accounts.

1. Do i keep Same Managed accounts that i currently i am using in Production environment?if not what is the reason to use separate accounts in staging servers?
2. Do i use same sharepoint farm & Sharepoint admin account in staging servers that i am using now in production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For staging environment their is no set of rules, but it is depend what staging means.

Best practice is never use the production managed accounts in staging, even never share service accounts between production farms.

if you share the accounts then you will risk your production farm.

- if accounts are used in staging and people gets the password n they can access production farm data using those service accounts.
- password management is tough.
- if working in staging,someone locked the account.it will bring production down.